# Why does React.js not have stateTypes?

Tags: reactjs

React components conceptually split their data into *props*, immutable data passed from their parent, and *state*, mutable data maintained locally.  One thing I like about React is its support for limited type checking in the form of [propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html).  Why is there not a similar concept for state (e.g. stateTypes)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using so-called *stateTypes* wouldn't give you much of a benefit.

As the official React site says about propTypes:

> As your app grows it's helpful to ensure that your components are used correctly.

The important thing to remember here is that propTypes checks if you passed correct data to the current element **in the place where you render this component**. You can reuse the component as many times as you wish, therefore it could easily happen that you forgot to pass appropriate properties to it.

Therefore, checking data passed from "other source" is more important and more beneficial than checking the data you just use when you write the component itself. If you could work with the information from state somewhere else, which you cannot, it would be worth using.

Anyway, it's all just a practical tool for easier development, which must be turned off on the production environment.

Conclusion: maybe this question is a bit opinion-based. I believe, that using *stateTypes* wouldn't help much if you declared your state in constructor (ES2015) or getInitialState, and just several lines below the exactly same information, only in the form of *stateTypes*.

Comment: It would still be nice to be warned when you set a state with the wrong type 'shape'.

Comment: it could do help, for example in my case I have a schemaless model's property in my mongoose's schema. The aime is that it allows me to put data property dynamically in. But my data should follow specific even if the number and name of property can change. It hence nice to be able to "schematize" my react.component in order to avoid datatypes error when post document to my database.

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence. Having experience with Typescript, I feel that type checking is as useful with state as it is with props. Without it, you can inadvertently change the state just any way and add wrong state properties without ever knowing unless you debug.

Comment: Hello, I was thinking of creating an issue on React repo to discuss about this and propose this. has anyone done this before ? If so, can anyone give me link to it ?

Thanks