# Making propTypes mandatory and is there stateTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [React documentaton](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html), the following has been mentioned under the heading `propValidation`:

```
React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    // You can declare that a prop is a specific JS primitive. By default, these
    // are all optional.
    optionalArray: React.PropTypes.array,
    optionalBool: React.PropTypes.bool,

.....
```

It is mentioned in the comment that **"these are all optional"**. How can I make it mandatory for that component ?

Also, similar to `propTypes` is there `stateTypes` which corresponds to `this.state` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can declare required props as follows:

```
React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    myPropStringRequired: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    myPropArrayRequired: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    myPropBooleanRequired: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
...
```

As per the second question about `stateTypes`, please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220201/why-does-react-js-not-have-statetypes).

Comment: Thanks, do you know about `stateTypes` thing ?

Comment: Not really, but i've updated my answer with a link to a question that might help you